# haskell if true then break or continue loop

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am fairly new to Haskell.

I want to pass two items:

First a list of numbers as strings say `["1","2","3","4"]` and I want to see if each of these items appears in  random string of numbers say `"14321"`

e.g `myFunction ["6","2","3"] "1234"`

My return value will be a maybe type where i want to return `Just("the number found", "14321")`.
With the first return param will be the number found in the list, and the second being the string originally passed.

The thing is, I only want to return the first instance of a match as a maybe, and if there is no match's return nothing.

I am unsure how to do a loop like this, to check if one matchs and if so return and finish or keep going to the next item in the list.

I have this:

```
isMatch :: [String] -> String -> Maybe (String,String)
isMatch (x:xs) test | x `isInfixOf` test = Just (x, test)
                    | otherwise = Nothing
```

It should work if the first match is true, but if not, how can I get it to continue onto the next in the list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems strange to return the argument in the `Just` – the caller already knows what `test` is, so why return it again?

Comment: It is just a theoretical question. I am going to want to return other things later in that Just.

Comment: The `otherwise = Nothing` case looks wrong. If `x` is not an infix of `test`, you want to examine `xs` recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me transliterate the code you have:

> If the first element in the list is found, then return it. Else abort.

but what you want is

> If the first element in the list is found, then return it. Else do the same thing, but with just the rest of the list.

And also

> If the list is empty, nothing can be found, so return `Nothing`.

Does that help you?

Comment: That is what i am trying to do. I should have just explained it like that the first time. Being new to haskell, i do not know how to test if it does not return nothing and then recall itself.

Comment: You have "else abort". You need "else call the same thing with a smaller list". What is a big challenge here? Do you have doubts about how to call your function, or perhaps identifying what the smaller list is?

Comment: @Sarah Note that the rewording of your question given by Joachim translates into Haskell almost directly. Try to adapt your code following this hint.

Comment: To the downvoter: Please always justify why you downvote a question or answer.

Answer (score 3):

> The thing is, I only want to return the first instance of a match as a maybe, and if there is no match's return nothing.

The function `find` from `Data.List` does exactly that:

```
isMatch xs test = find (`isInfixOf` test) xs
```

This gives a nice concise definition, but if you're learning Haskell, you should try to figure out how to write the version with explicit recursion as well.

If you insist on including `test` in the result, you can then use `fmap` to modify a `Just` value:

```
isMatch xs test = fmap (\x -> (x, test)) $ find (`isInfixOf` test) xs
```

or with the `TupleSections` extension:

```
isMatch xs test = fmap (, test) $ find (`isInfixOf` test) xs
```

But with a name like `isMatch` I would actually expect a `Bool` return value; perhaps `findMatch` would be better.